# Upgrading Ubuntu slows Laptop down

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

I've a question considering upgrading Ubuntu to the new version. I've changed from 13.04 to 14.04 the system works great. I've noticed that if you upgrade the system it always gets slower. It is like having a a part of the old system still on the computer. Is there a possibility to "clean up" all the old stuff thats left over? 
For example: I've created a password to encrypt before the computer is started but now it loads first something and then goes into the "old mode" for entering the password like in 13.04

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu removes old packages at upgrade, so it does the clean install. but you can use `apt-get autoremove` to remove old packages again. when a version of LTS is out please wait to get it completely stable such as 14.04.2. there are lots of such small bugs which need to get fixed.